Is there a sequence satisfying the following conditions?
Consider a sequence $ \{ \alpha_k \} \in (0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ such that the following conditions hold:

$\alpha_1 = 1$;
For all $k > 1$, the inequality $\frac{1-\alpha_k}{\alpha_k^2} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha_{k-1}^2}$ holds;
$\alpha_k^2 = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{k^s}\right)$ for some $s > 2$.

Is such a sequence possible, and if so, what could be an example of $\{\alpha_k\}$? If not, can a proof be provided to show the impossibility of such a sequence? Thanks a lot for any discussion!

Motivation: As required, I will outline the major motivation behind this inquiry. The existence of such a sequence is crucial for analyzing the rate of convergence of certain algorithms. For instance, it is well-established that Nesterov’s gradient descent algorithm achieves a superior rate of convergence, on the order of $\mathcal{O}(1/k^2)$, compared to the traditional gradient descent’s $\mathcal{O}(1/k)$, for the class of functions $f$ that are both convex and $L$-smooth. The key rationale supporting this acceleration is the existence of a sequence where ( s = 2 ). Here, we aim to extend this inquiry further by asking whether such sequences exist for ( s > 2 ).

No, this is not possible, since $\alpha_k\geq 1/k$ for all $k$. If not, there is a first time it fails, say $\alpha_k<1/k$ but $\alpha_{k-1}\geq 1/(k-1)$ for some $k>1$. But then
$$\frac{1-\alpha_k}{\alpha_k^2}>k(k-1)>(k-1)^2\geq\frac{1}{\alpha_{k-1}^2},$$ contradiction.

Great answer! You nailed it. This shows that $\alpha_k^2$ can at best decrease as fast as $\mathcal{O}(1/k^2)$, and it just can't drop faster as $\mathcal{O}(1/k^s)$ for any $s > 2$.
